# Prove: $\int_{S^{n-1}}f(\langle x,v\rangle)dVol_{n-1}= Vol_{S^{n-2}} \int_{-1}^{1} f(|v|t)\cdot (1-t^2)^\frac{n-3}{2}dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, manifolds

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function, $v\in \mathbb{R}$ a fixed point.
> Prove:
> $\int_{S^{n-1}}f(\langle x,v\rangle)dVol_{n-1}= Vol_{S^{n-2}} \int_{-1}^{1} f(|v|t)\cdot (1-t^2)^\frac{n-3}{2}dt $

I need to use co-area.
I know that for an orthogonal transformation $A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $\int_{S^{n-1}}f(\langle x,v\rangle)dVol_{n-1}= $\int_{S^{n-1}}f(\langle Ax,v\rangle)dVol_{n-1}=$\int_{S^{n-1}}f(\langle x,A^{-1}v\rangle)dVol_{n-1}$ and then we can take $A^{-1}v=(0,0,..,|v|)$ and then we get:
$\int_{S^{n-1}}f(\langle x,v\rangle)dVol_{n-1}=\int_{S^{n-1}}f(|v|x_n)dVol_{n-1}$.
And I'm not sure how to continue, would appreciate your help:)

Answer (score 1):

You went in the right direction. The next step is to use cylindrical coordinate -- every point on $S^{n-1}$ can be written as $(\sqrt{1-t^2}\xi,t)$ where $\xi\in S^{n-2}$. Now you must figure out how to represent the volume-measure $dVol_{n-1}$ in terms of $t$ and $dVol_{n-2}$. It turns out that in these coordinates,
$$dVol_{n-1}=dVol_{n-2}(1-t^2)^{(n-3)/2}dt$$